# Unwanted recursion - how to avoid child click event from passing to parent in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dom-events, infinite-recursion

I have a some elements, roughly like this:

```
<div>
    <a>
<div>
```

When a user clicks anywhere on the div, I want the `a` element to be clicked - for usability purposes.

Simple right? So I wrote this:

```
$('div.class').click(function(){  
    $('a.class', this).click();
    console.log('clicked'); 
});
```

Trouble is, this clicks the `a` element alright, but the event propagates to the `div`, which clicks it, which clicks the `a`, which... well you can see where it's going.

I cooked up a sample on JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XD6Vm/2/)
but it doesn't show the console log. So if you click, Firebug doesn't show anything. but my local site sets Firebug crazy with logs (clicked) so much that in the end script gets killed saying `too much recursion on this page`

How do I stop this recursion?

Yes I know, I know that I can use `window.location` for this purpose, but clicking the link does some extra work and also uses window history for browsers, so I really want to click that vicious `a` without making it click its Dad. Or Mom. Or whatever that `div` is.

**PLEASE READ**

Since everyone is suggesting the same thing over and over again, and it's not working, please take a look this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XD6Vm/2/). Try it and see if it works before you answer. When you click on a `div`, Google should load up. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you return false to stop the event?

Comment: just tried, I didn't expect it to work and it didn't.

Comment: woops, that down vote isn't from me, just so you know.

Comment: No Worries. I was just shooting from the hip. That's what I get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is is your markup:

```html
<div>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

...all you will need to do is in your css do something like:

```css
div a { display: block};
```

The anchor element will then stretch and occupy all the available space in the parent `div`. However, if some other elements exist within that `div`, you could do:

```
$('a.class').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert('you clicked on me');
});

$('div.class').click( function () {
  $(this).children('a.class').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, its not doing anything. Can you try this on jsfiddle and see if you can get it to work?

Comment: It worked for me of course you have to add the class="class" for both the div and the a tag, check the result on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wB7uq/

Comment: and on the second version below i added css so you can see that the event get triggered if you click on the anchor or the parent div, check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/wB7uq/2/

Comment: excellent! I was trying to stop propagation from div itself, I see the code is slightly restructured and the propagation has to be stopped from child! Thank you very much! cant tell you how happy I am to have learnt this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `event.stopPropagation()` method.

Comment: hi, says event is undefined. I am googling up on event, but can you please try on jsfiddle to see if you can get it to work? many thanks

Comment: Hi, got it to work (I mean, got stopPropagation to work - i had to add event to function) - but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: stopPropagation only works on ancestor events. It will stil try and fire because you are referring to the event itself. You need to restructure your code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$('selector').attr('onclick')()
```

Comment: I think actually TheSuperTramp's solution is a more sensible approach to what I am suggesting

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the click event on the child node, just set the browser location to the `href` value

```
$('div.class').click(function(){
  location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.class').click(function(event){  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('a.class', this).click();
    console.log('clicked'); 
});
```

You need to add the `event` argument and a `stopPropagation` method to the handler.

Comment: tried that, doesn't do anything. Tried ``event.preventDefault()`` as well. no luck :(

Comment: can't you make the a spread over the div. that way when the user clicks on the div, it gets clicked on the link.